# How to say "not a bracket" in an Emacs regex?

Tags: regex, emacs, regex-negation

I want to find all lines (in a SQL script) which don't have the `dbo.` or `[dbo].` prefix (where it should normally appear to fully qualify names).

For example, in the below file:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mo_scenario_em]
DROP CONSTRAINT [mo_scenario_em_scenario_id]
ALTER TABLE [team_assoc]                         -- <<< missing prefix
DROP CONSTRAINT [team_assoc_org_id]
ALTER TABLE dbo.asset_trans
DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__asset_tra__mod_f__5E90642B]
ALTER TABLE eq                                   -- <<< missing prefix
DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__eq__source_recor__2498CCC0]
```

I'd like my command to display lines 3 and 7.

My *not-working* take on this:

```
(defun show-missing-prefix ()
  "Show lines where there is no `dbo.' or `[dbo.]' prefix."
  (interactive)
  (occur (concat "ALTER TABLE [^d][^b][^o]"
                 "\\|" "ALTER TABLE \\[[^d][^b][^o]\\]"
                 "\\|" "CREATE FUNCTION [^d][^b][^o]"
                 )))
```

It does not work as I don't see how to match lines with `ALTER TABLE` for example, but without both `dbo.` and `[dbo].`.

The problem is I don't know **how to write "not a bracket" in the regexp** -- `[^\\[]` and `[^\\]]` do not work AFAICS.

Of course, it will have to be generalized to other SQL keywords, such as:

- alter procedure
- drop function
- drop table
- from
- insert into
- update

and be case-insensitive, but that should be OK once the skeleton does the job.

Is this possible in a quite simple way?  (Or does it already exist somehow?)

Comment: See (elisp) [Regexp Special](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html). E.g., "*To include a ‘]’ in a character alternative, you must make it the first character.  For example, ‘[]a]’ matches ‘]’ or ‘a’.... (As explained below, you cannot use ‘\]’ to include a ‘]’ inside a character alternative, since ‘\’ is not special there.)*"

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how to say "not a bracket" as ^ also has to be the first character to indicate the negation.

Comment: It says: "*The character following the ‘^’ is treated as if it were first (in other words, ‘-’ and ‘]’ are not special there).*"

Comment: As an aside `[^d][^b][^o]` excludes `abo` and `dbb`.

Answer (score 3):

As Drew, Triplee, and jmg have said:

*Not a bracket*, you can reverse the order: `[^][]`

Case-insensitive `show-missing-prefix`, as posted by question author in comments below, with missing `$`:

```
(defun show-missing-prefix ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "\\(alter\\|drop\\|insert\\) *\\(table\\) *\\(\\[?[^\\. ]+\\]?\\)$"))
```

Another suggestion for solving the problem, you could start with something like this:

```
query-replace-regexp
```

Regexp Match String:

```
\(alter\|drop\|insert\) *\(table\) *\(\[?[^. ]+\]?\)$
```

To-String:

```
\1 \2 [dbo].\3)
```

Use escaped `()` to define numeric groups, referenced in the replace string: in this case, `\1` is the operation (3 provided), `\2` is the operand (only *table* currently), and `\3` is the named object, which specifies a series of one or more characters that do not include `.` or  (space).

On your example, after removing the *missing prefix* comments, this matched lines 3 and 7 and added the prefix.

Emacs comes with `re-builder`, which allows you to get real-time feedback while building a regular expression, but you have to make sure you're using the correct syntax mode.  `read`, the default mode, is for using REs in programming; so to see the above regex in `re-builder`, you have to switch to `string` syntax mode, which is for REs used interactively.  (Change the syntax mode using `C-c TAB`.)

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/why-do-regular-expressions-created-with-the-regex-builder-use-syntax-different-f

There are lots of other packages out there that look they could help.
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

Additionally, if you wanted the full escaped lisp of the command after finding success (interactively), take a look at `command-history`:

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\(alter\\|drop\\|insert\\) *\\(table\\) *\\(\\[?[^\\. ]+\\]?\\)$" "\\1 \\2 [dbo].\\3" nil)
```

Comment: `re-builder` handles complex regexps and groups just fine; your regexp is just wrong. For instance with `\([?[^\. ]+]?\)` you are clearly trying to use un-escaped `[` and `]` to match those literal characters; you probably didn't mean to include backslashes in the character alternative; and you would match more things without the `$` anchor (or observe why the pattern doesn't extend that far, at any rate).

Comment: With the general syntax you've shown (single backslashes for escaping), you'd most likely need to switch re-builder to `string` syntax, using `C-c TAB` (as `read` syntax is the default).  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568 may be helpful regarding that.

Comment: Thanks phils.  Updated `re-builder` info and escaped the brackets in the regex so it works in `string` syntax mode.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get - yet - how it solves my question. Using your code, I've written the function `(defun show-missing-prefix ()
  (interactive)
  (occur "\\(ALTER\\|DROP\\|INSERT\\) *\\(TABLE\\) *\\(\\[?[^\\. ]+\\]?\\)"))`
but it shows me all 4 lines, instead of the 2 where the prefix is missing (that's the goal: showing if there are any erroneous lines)... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you may have missed the `$` at the end of the string to require looking at the full line.  Also I would make the string lowercase, as that will make it case-insensitive.  As soon as you use upper-case characters in the match string, it becomes case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs regular expression the following string matches any character that is not an opening bracket: `[^[]`. At least in Emacs 25.3.1.

Comment: This should work all the way back to Thompson's original `grep` 0.1